# Material-UI: How to control the position of the expanded autocomplete input?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have some autocomplete fields:
[some autocomplete fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCAUJ.png)
and i noticed that if i select multiple options, when i click on the input its height increases, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9yt2.png), pushing everything down.

Is there a way to control that? I want to make it go above the content when expanded like that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this can help you I think https://codesandbox.io/s/select-multiple-option-with-mui-and-react-hook-form-2kv2o

You can use the FormController and give it a width like shown in the sandbox

Reference - [React - Material-UI - How to use Select with multiple values inside react-hook-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273514/react-material-ui-how-to-use-select-with-multiple-values-inside-react-hook-f)